# How to disable submit button before all quiz question checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<style>
    .hide {
        display:none;
    }
    .question {
        padding: 25px;
    }
    input[type="radio"] {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .btton {
        padding: 15px 25px;
    }
</style>
<div class="questions" id="question-div">
    <?php
        $i=1;
        echo '<div class="questions" id="question-div">
                <form action="" method="POST" id="question-form">';
                foreach($quiz as $r)
                {
                    echo '<div id="div-'.$i.'" class="question'; if($i>1)echo ' hide';echo '">
                            <input type="hidden" class="classesID" data-id="'.$r->classesID.'" />
                            <input type="hidden" class="questionID" data-id="'.$r->videoquizID.'" />
                            <p>Question '.$i.' : <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="'.$r->videoquizID.'" id="'.$r->videoquizID.'" />'.$r->question.'</p>
                            <label class="radio-inline" data-id="'.$i.'" >
                                <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-'.$r->videoquizID.'" value="'.$r->option1.'">'.$r->option1.'
                            </label><br/>
                            <label class="radio-inline" data-id="'.$i.'" >
                                <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-'.$r->videoquizID.'" value="'.$r->option2.'">'.$r->option2.'
                            </label><br/>
                            <label class="radio-inline" data-id="'.$i.'" >
                                <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-'.$r->videoquizID.'" value="'.$r->option3.'">'.$r->option3.'
                            </label><br/>
                            <label class="radio-inline" data-id="'.$i.'" >
                                <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-'.$r->videoquizID.'" value="'.$r->option4.'">'.$r->option4.'
                            </label><br/>
                        </div>';
                        $i++;
                }
                echo '<div class="btton">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="buttons btn btn-primary hide" id="prev">Prev</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="buttons btn btn-primary hide" id="next" data-id="'.count($quiz).'">Next</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="buttons btn btn-success hide" id="submit">Submit</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="refresh btn btn-danger">Skip Quiz</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>';
    ?>
</div>  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var maxq = <?php echo count($quiz); ?>;
    $('.radio-inline').click(function(e) {
        var id = parseInt($(this).data('id'));
        if(id==1) $('.buttons').addClass('hide');
        if(id!=(maxq-1))
        {
            $('#next').removeClass('hide');
        }
        var next = (id+1);
        var prev = (id-1);
        $('#next').data('id',next);
        $('#prev').data('id',prev);
    });
    $('#next').click(function(e) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('.buttons').addClass('hide');
        if(id==(maxq-1)) 
        {
            $('#submit,#prev').removeClass('hide');
        }
        else {$('.buttons').addClass('hide');$('#prev').removeClass('hide');}
        $('.question').addClass('hide');
        $('#div-'+id).removeClass('hide');
        var next = id+1;
        var prev = id-1;
        $('#next').data('id',next);
        $('#prev').data('id',prev);
    });
    $('#prev').click(function(e) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#prev').removeClass('hide');
        if(id==1)$('.buttons').addClass('hide');
        $('.question').addClass('hide');
        $('#div-'+id).removeClass('hide');
        var next = id+1;
        var prev = id-1;
        $('#next').data('id',next);
        $('#prev').data('id',prev);
    });
</script>
```

In this question I have created simple quiz which is working fine but the problem is that `submit` button is enable if quiz option is select or not. I don't want to enable my submit button before all quiz option check. Once all question option check then submit button enable. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: IDs must be unique. You have repeated IDs.

Comment: IDs are unique @gaetanoM

Comment: No, they are not.  This **id="question-div"** is repeated.

Comment: @gaetanoM I have change `id` but still submit button `enable`

Comment: @navi The ID comment wasn't related to your issue I don't think , it was just a general observation that your code was untidy / incorrect. It has the potential to cause other problems if you do that kind of thing.

Comment: Anyway. Start by having the submit button disabled / hidden as you do now. Then, each time the user selects a radio button option, make your code check whether all the radio button groups have a selected value or not. If they do, enable the button. (You should be easily able to research how to do each of those individual steps, they are quite simple Javascript tasks. If you get stuck with a specific problem within one of those tasks, update your code. Right now your question appears to lack a bit of thought / effort / research to try and work out for yourself the likely steps to solving it).

Comment: start by having it disabled - you already have a check for removing the "next" button, if there is no more steps - Use that check to enable the submit button, and done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart the duplicated IDs I wuold suggest to use a change event handler on radio buttons and count if the number of checked radios is the same of all  div with class question.

In order to toggle the disabled class you can use  [.toggleClass( className, state )](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) :

```js
$('#question-form :radio').on('change', function (e) {
    var rChecked = $('#question-form div.question :radio:checked').length;
    var divrChecked = $('#question-form div.question').length;
    $('#submit').toggleClass('disabled', rChecked != divrChecked);
})
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}

.question {
    padding: 25px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.btton {
    padding: 15px 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="questions" id="question-div1">
    <div class="questions" id="question-div2">
        <form action="" method="POST" id="question-form">
            <div id="div-1'" class="question">
                <input type="hidden" class="classesID" data-id="classesID1"/>
                <input type="hidden" class="questionID" data-id="videoquizID1"/>

                <p>Question 1 : <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="'videoquizID1" id="videoquizID1"/>question1
                </p>
                <label class="radio-inline" data-id="1">
                    <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-videoquizID1" value="option1">option1
                </label><br/>
                <label class="radio-inline" data-id="1">
                    <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-videoquizID1" value="option2">option2
                </label><br/>
                <label class="radio-inline" data-id="1">
                    <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-videoquizID1" value="option3">option3
                </label><br/>
                <label class="radio-inline" data-id="1">
                    <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-videoquizID1" value="option4">option4
                </label><br/>
            </div>

            <div id="div-2'" class="question">
                <input type="hidden" class="classesID" data-id="classesID2"/>
                <input type="hidden" class="questionID" data-id="videoquizID2"/>

                <p>Question 2 : <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="'videoquizID2" id="videoquizID2"/>question1
                </p>
                <label class="radio-inline" data-id="2">
                    <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-videoquizID2" value="option1">option1
                </label><br/>
                <label class="radio-inline" data-id="2">
                    <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-videoquizID2" value="option2">option2
                </label><br/>
                <label class="radio-inline" data-id="2">
                    <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-videoquizID2" value="option3">option3
                </label><br/>
                <label class="radio-inline" data-id="2">
                    <input type="radio" class="answer" name="a-videoquizID2" value="option4">option4
                </label><br/>
            </div>
            <div class="btton">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="buttons btn btn-primary hide" id="prev">Prev</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="buttons btn btn-primary hide" id="next" data-id="'.count($quiz).'">Next</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="buttons btn btn-success disabled" id="submit">Submit</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="refresh btn btn-danger">Skip Quiz</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```